# What is the Meaning and Origin of the 'Eyes that See, Ears that Hear' Metaphor in the Bible?

Tags: metaphor

In several passages of the Bible, there are intriguing references to the metaphor of eyes that see (or do not see) and ears that hear (or do not hear). I'm curious about the deeper meanings and origins of this metaphor. Here are a few examples:

- Matthew 13:16 - "But blessed are your eyes because they see, and your ears because they hear."
- Deuteronomy 29:4 - "But to this day the LORD has not given you a heart to understand or eyes to see or ears to hear."
- Luke 14:35 - "It is fit neither for the soil nor for the manure pile; it is thrown out. 'Whoever has ears to hear, let them hear.'"
  My question is two-fold:

Meaning: What are the intended meanings or implications behind this metaphor in these contexts?
Origin: Is this metaphor unique to the Judeo-Christian tradition, or does it have earlier origins or parallels in other ancient texts or cultures?
I'm looking for insights that delve into the theological, historical, or literary aspects of this metaphor.

Comment: I don't have a bibliography for it in front of me, but there is a theory that that culture divided Man not into body, soul, and spirit, but into eyes+heart, ears+mouth, and "everything else" epitomized by the feet. This lines up with MANY verses.

Comment: @fumanchu,your concept of dividing Man into eyes+heart, ears+mouth, and 'everything else' represented by the feet is intriguing. It offers a novel perspective on human experience, linking sight and feelings, communication through listening and speaking, and symbolizing life's journey via the feet. I'm eager to learn more, especially about its alignment with various verses and its cultural or historical background. Can you share more details or references?

Answer (score 1):

Mk 4:11-13

> And he said unto them, Unto you it is given to know the mystery of the kingdom of God, but unto them that are without, all these things are done in parables: 12 That seeing they may see, and not perceive; and hearing they may hear , and not understand; lest at any time they should be converted, and their sins should be forgiven them.  13 And he said unto them, Know ye not this parable? and how then will ye know all parables?

Jesus is saying only the converted will understand his parables, because they have spiritual eyes and ears to understand God's instruction. They are born again.